# Git new commit as an older version of a project

Tags: git

In Git, is it possible to do something like this?

```
master B - C - D
```

to this?

```
master A - B - C - D
```

I've an existing project using Git and everything went fine. But I've found an older version of that project and I wish to commit it to the same repo, but put it as A and make it looks like it is the earliest version of that project. Is it possible to do this in Git? or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fairly easy to do, but I will start with the standard warning to know that it will be changing `B-C-D` into `B'-C'-D'`, that is, they will have new commit hashes and there will be conflicts with any existing clones of the repository.  Assuming your fine with that...

We start with an understanding that git is organized as a series of commits, each with a pointer to its parent(s).  In this way a tree of commits is created.

```
tree 1:  B - C - D
```

Since what you are wanting to do is add something before the first commit -- and there is nothing to address before the first commit -- we have to create a new tree to do this.

To create a new tree, we will start with an empty commit.  Having an empty commit as the first commit of a repository makes things like this easier.  This is done with the following commands (numbers added for later reference)

```
git checkout --orphan new-branch            (1)
git rm -r --force --cached .                (2)
git clean -fd                               (3)
git clean -fd                               (3a)
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initialize'    (4)
```

This creates a new branch that is not connected to any other branch (1).  This leaves all the files in the working directory cached and ready to be commited.  We don't want to commit those files, so (2) removes them from the cache; while (3) removes them from the directory.  It is sometimes necessary to clean twice because ignored files will not be cleaned, but the .gitignore file will -- leaving the files in need of being cleaned again.

Finally, (4) creates an empty commit as the first commit in this branch.  The `--allow-empty` argument makes this possible -- and any message will do.

Now, add all the files from the earlier version of the project, `A`, and commit.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'A'


------------------
tree 1:  B - C - D
tree 2:  A
```

We are ready to move `B-C-D` onto `A`.  While still on `new-branch`, this command will move them.

```
git rebase -i --onto new-branch --root D
```

This will checkout `D`, walk the tree (rewind) back to the root `B` and moving each commit, in order, onto `A` -- making new commits each step of the way until it gets back to `D`.  **Note:  There is a strong probability you will have merge conflicts here, be prepared to handle them.**

When done the tree looks like this

```
tree 1: <empty>             <-- this will be garbage collected in time
tree 2: A - B' - C' - D'
```

At this point push back to any remote repository you may have -- you will need to force the push

```
git push --force <remote> <local-branch>:<remote-branch>
```

This will overwrite the remote branch -- **make sure this is what you want**.

That's all there is to it.  Just remember to not work on your only copy of the repository so you can re-clone and try again if it gets knotted up.  Other than that, I would suggest reading up on `git rebase ...` so you are familiar with what is happening -- and the quirks you may run into, depending on the complexity of `B-C-D` in your actual repository.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add A as a new commit and then rebase interactive to the commit before B (`rebase -i B~1`) to reorder the commits the way you want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a caveat.  Let's say you start with:

```
B - C - D
```

The result will be

```
A - B' - C' - D'
```

Note the "prime" marker—B' will have the same *tree* (contents) as B, but it will have a different SHA-1 hash because its parent is different.

The easiest way to do this is with grafts.  Create a repository that has both A and B in it:

```
A

B - C - D
```

Note how they don't connect to each other.  You connect them to each other with a "graft" ([Wiki page](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint)), which makes A the parent of B...

```
A
 \
  ...
     \
      B - C - D
```

I used a dotted line because the graft is temporary.  The graft is created by editing `.git/info/grafts` and writing:

```
<hash of B> <hash of A>
```

The graft is made permanent with the command:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This will change the graph to:

```
A - B' - C' - D'
```

After making it permanent, delete the grafts file.

The usual warnings apply—you are rewriting history, so anyone who has pulled your repository will have to use `git reset`, as long as they don't have local changes.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Each commit in Git is represented by a hash, and the "parent" commit is one of the element for the hash generation.

Therefore, if you change the parent of B, B will no longer be B (i.e. the hash will no longer be the same)

You can still do so by using rebase, that you create A first and rebase B,C,D... on A.  However, as I said before, the hash will no longer be the same.  If it is fine for you then go ahead for this :)